# Drop Down Not Loaded properly

Tags: asp.net, .net

Respected Users,

I have two drop downs in my applications as ddlCountry and ddlState.
I have database as

tlbCountry

ID(PK) | countryName

tlbState

ID(PK) | countryName | stateName

On loading of page I have loaded all the items in ddlCountry dropdown as

```
sqldataadapter da=new sqldataadapter("select countryName from tlbCountry",con);
dataset ds=new dataset();
da.fill(ds);
for(int i=0;i<ds.tables[0].rows.count;i++)
ddlCountry.items.add(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][0].toString());
```

When page gets loaded, upto this its working fine.
But,
When on Textchange or selection change event of ddlCountry, it makes attempt to take the values of corresponding states from tlbStates table as follows. Its not working, I have done that as follows,

```
sqldataadapter da=new sqldataadapter("select stateName from tlbState where countryName like '"+ddlCountry.selectedItem.toString()+"'",con);
dataset ds=new dataset();
da.fill(ds);
for(int i=0;i<ds.tables[0].rows.count;i++)
ddlState.items.add(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][0].toString());
```

In this case its not loading the ddlState drop down.

When I turn on autopostback for ddlCountry, it again reloads the page with no values in ddlState.
What can be the issue?

Note:- I have used AJAX UPDATE PANEL.

Comment: Try using `ddlCountry.selectedItem.Text` in your on change of ddlCountry

Comment: Extract the State query while debugging and run it directly in SQL Server and share your findings.

Comment: @Behroz while debugging i found that it is not going into event function selectedindexchanged for ddlcountry combo where i tries to load states in ddlStates for corrosponding ddlCountry. I made autopostback true for ddlCountry then also it didnt worked

Comment: ahan, on selectionChange the event should fire. Now, verify that in  markup of your ASPX page ,can you see the event name in the markup of the dropdown tlbState ?

Comment: no its onselectedindexchange event that i have used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your query to this:

```
"select stateName from tlbState where countryName = '" + ddlCountry.Text + "'"
```

Populate your `ddlCountry` on Page_Load only when the request is not a `PostBack`

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        { 
            //Load Countires
            sqldataadapter da = new sqldataadapter("select countryName from tlbCountry", con);
            dataset ds = new dataset();
            da.fill(ds);
            for (int i = 0; i < ds.tables[0].rows.count; i++)
                ddlCountry.items.add(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][0].toString());
        }
    }
```

Comment: my query might be wrong, but primary question is that, it is not comming in the onselectedindexchanged event function for ddlCountry. So even though this query is write, program flow is not comming upto this.

Comment: Check that you are not adding the countries on every `Load`. This would reset the `SelectedItem` and cause the event not to be fired.

Comment: yeah i am adding it onload.

Comment: You must populate the list only once, otherwise the event will not fire. See my edited answer.

Comment: ohh yeah...i understood the problem

Answer (score 0):

Hope it will help you.

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{ 
  //here bind country drop down on page load event.
}
```

and then  on selection change event of ddlCountry bind state dropdown